# jQuerying content made by VueJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I am sure this has been answered before but as I am new with VueJs I do not know  the correct terminology.

I have a table of data that is created by Vue (`<template v-for="group in groups">` etc). It Gets this information from an ajax call in the Vue object's `ready()` method. (`this.$set('groups', response.data.groups);`

Each cell of the table as a span element that I want to... `$('.pie').peity();` on to convert the text into an svg.

Where should this code be placed?

Comment: What's with the dot after pie? $('.pie.').peity();

Comment: Just a typo when copy + pasting to stackoverflow

Comment: Ok. Post your complete code. We can't see anything here. Do the span have the class "pie"?

Comment: Yes it does. The question isn't so much about why isn't this working. I am quite familiar with jQuery for instance. It is more about where is the correct place the run code like this after Vue has loaded it onto the page.

Comment: I see. It sounded like you were having problems making it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing this right after the table is loaded, try using Vue's NextTick:

```
this.$nextTick(function() {
    $('.pie').peity();
});
```

Comment: So I put that in my ready method, after the content is loaded successfully. Thanks.